# How to read the arguments passed from cloud function into Dataproc SparkOperator in composer in GCP

Tags: python-3.x, string, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

How to read the arguments passed from cloud function into Dataproc SparkOperator in composer in GCP.
i'm able to read those into composer by passing the data between composer and cloud function.
I've a hard-coded string argument and all i have to do is append this arg to Json value which i read from cloud function.When i'm trying to append the argument..the argument of dataproc spark operator is not identifying it.Is there anyway to append this string with the Json received from cloud function.

Comment: What kind of arguments are you using in Cloud Functions?

Comment: I'm sending JSON arguments in cloud function.